# Shift register using ATMEGA328p

Tags: c, atmega

I want to learn more about the shiftout function used with Arduinos and used the implementation with my ATMEGA328p.

**The Setup**

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL
#define BAUD 9600UL
#define LSBFIRST 0
#define MSBFIRST 1
#define HIGH 0x1
#define LOW  0x0
#define INPUT 0x0
#define OUTPUT 0x1

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <USART.h>
#include <pinDefines.h>

#define DATA PD7
#define LATCH PB2
#define CLOCK PB0

uint8_t leds = 0;

void shiftOut(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val)
{
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST) { 
            PORTD |= (!!(val & (HIGH << i)) << DATA);
        } else {
            PORTD |= (!!(val & (HIGH << (7 - i))) << DATA);
        }

        PORTB |= (HIGH << clockPin);
        PORTB |= (LOW << clockPin);
    }
}

void updateShiftRegister() {
    PORTB |= (LOW << LATCH);
    shiftOut(DATA, CLOCK, LSBFIRST, leds);
    PORTB |= (HIGH << LATCH);
}

void setupRegisters() {
    DDRD = 0xff;
    DDRB = 0xff;
}


int main(void)
{
    setupRegisters();
    leds = 1;
    updateShiftRegister();
    _delay_ms(2000);
    leds = 0;
    updateShiftRegister();

    return (0);
}
```

I created an example to understand more about the function, but the outcome does not add up to what I expected to see.

Given my example, I would expect LED1 to turn on and turn off after 2sec. It turns on, but it does not turn off afterwards. Did I miss anything? I am searching for 2hrs now for the error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

`DDRD` is the "Data Direction Register D". If you want to use the whole Port D as output, you should set it to 0xFF, else parts of it are used as input, what causes your unexepected results.

I haven't checked, but it's possible that Port D is used by something more than just the General Digital I/O (e.g. by JTAG) what overrides the `PORTD` settings. Just read [the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf). By the way, there also are some example programs.

Comment: Hi! I tried, that but it didn't change. Here is my adapted code above to clean up a bit. Why does it not turn the LED off?

Comment: Try to debug the code. So first check, whether you can set the output pins right (e.g. `DDRD = 0xFF; PORTD = 0xAA`). If so, then start checking the rest command by command.
By the way, `PORTB |= (LOW << clockPin)` is wrong. What you want is `PORTB &= ~(1<< clockPin)`

Comment: By the way, you're in the wrong forum. Thry posting at https://embdev.net/forum/microcontrollers